# how to make checkboxes square for ios in ionic framework?

Tags: ios, checkbox, ionic-framework, ionic2

**ionic check boxes** are showing square in android but in **IOS** its shows rounded.

How we can make them square for IOS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use checkbox-square system defind css class in your checkbox class.

```
<ion-checkbox class="checkbox-square" ng-model="isCheckedCommercial">value 1</ion-checkbox>
```

this will helps you.
If you have any query let me know.

Comment: This worked for me when "mode=md" didn't. Possibly because I'm on Ionic 1.

Answer (score 3):

I just used this.

```
<ion-checkbox mode="md"></ion-checkbox>
```

Comment: add some description

Comment: The `mode` attribute can change the way the item is rendered. If you want circular checkboxes on non-ios devices, you can set the `mode` to 'ios'

Answer (score 1):

You can set globally with:
$ionicConfigProvider.form.checkbox("circle");

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', ...])
.config(function($ionicConfigProvider) {
  $ionicConfigProvider.form.checkbox("square");
  //code
})
```

More information: [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider/)

Answer (score 0):

Native iOS uses [switches](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-controls/switches/). Ionic tries to use components that are like native controls. Not too successfully this time, but perhaps circles are closer to the native iOS feeling. So I'd stick with it: using ionic means also to follow their design.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your scss file.

```
.checkbox-icon {
        border-radius: 0%!important
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain why this helps.

Comment: Ionics built in styling for checkboxes has a border-radius of 50% by default making it circle. So we override it with border-radius 0%!important to remove the styling causing the circle.

Answer (score 0):

Change checkbox-md will fix this issue.
in your html file set,
class="checkbox-md"

Answer (score 0):

the code bellow works for the Ionic version 3:

```
.item {
      .checkbox {
        .checkbox-icon {
          border-radius: 0% !important;
        }
      }
    }
```